# Java Thread StackOverflowError

Tags: java

...

```
Thread showWordThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(config.delayTime * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
            this.run();
        }
    };
    showWordThread.run();
}
```

...

It had run for about 5 minutes before error occured:

Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Why?

I had tried this:

```
Thread showWordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(config.delayTime * 1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    showWordThread.start();
```

But error still occured.

Comment: What you call `this.run`, this statement has not any good reason!!!

Comment: I want to call it(with something inside) every 1 minute.

Comment: Ok,I wrote my answer , I hope it useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

Others have explained that you should use a `while` loop instead. You're *also* trying to call the `run` method inside your anonymous class declaration. Additionally, you should call `start`, rather than `run` - when the new thread has started, it will call `run` automatically. I'd actually suggest implementing `Runnable` rather than extending `Thread`, too. So you want:

```
Thread showWordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        while (someCondition) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(config.delayTime * 1000);
                // Presumably do something useful here...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
});
showWordThread.start();
```

Alternatively, consider using a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: @hnimnart: If it's the same error, then it must be in some code you haven't shown us. The code above will *not* result in stack overflow.

Comment: @hnimnart: So not the same error :) If it's a different error, I suggest you start a new question. No point in mixing the two.

Comment: @user2910110: Please don't use comments to draw attention to unrelated questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `run` method as recursively. Java holds call information(such as parameters) in stack memory so when you are calling a method recursively and there isn't any end point, stack memory will consumed and `StackOverflow` exception throws.

Maybe you want increasing `Heap Size` of `JVM` but this solution don't solve your problem and `StackOverflow` will occurred .

I guess you want run a thread continually. I recommend following code:

```
Thread showWordThread = new Thread() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
            try 
            {
                sleep(config.delayTime * 1000);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
            // this.run(); this snnipet code  make error
        }
    };
    showWordThread.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have infinity recursive, you should change the code to:

```
    Thread showWordThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(config.delayTime * 1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    };
    showWordThread.start();
```

Comment: This is still infinite recursion.

Comment: But I want to do something in "every 1 minute"

Comment: @Jeffrey, my mistake, forgot to remove the recursive call

Answer (score 1):

Don't call run() from within the run() method. That'll definitely produce a stack overflow because you keep reentering the same method with no exit condition. Instead use a `while` loop.

```
Thread showWordThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(condition) {
            try {
                sleep(config.delayTime * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    showWordThread.start();
}
```

Comment: The end of this is somewhat dodgy - your `run()` call should be `start()`, and the semi-colon after the brace should be one brace later.

Comment: Whoops. blind copy/paste. Thanks. +1 to your answer since you posted your identical while I was still typing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your function calls itself each time you run it.
That results in a stack overflow.

Comment: What should I do now? I want to run it every 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you call `run` method (`this.run()`) from itself?